# Como usar o pattern para delimitar um número mínimo em um input text?

Tags: php, html5, regex, input

Olá, preciso definir que o número mínimo inserido em um input do tipo text seja o número 5, tentei da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="text" name="someName" id="someId" required="required" pattern="(([1-9]?[0-9]?[5-9]?)|([0-9]?[5-9]?)|([5-9]?))"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hiperportal/Qa5xS/2/

Porém não está funcionando, apenas funciona se digitado 04, e não somente 4.

Obs.: número mínimo 5, número máximo 999.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso provavelmente resolverá.

```
 <input type="text" name="someName" id="someId" required="required" pattern="((^[5-9]$)|(^[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]$))"/>
```

[Teste o HTML no jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/hLwL3rod/)

Explicação da expressão:

```
((^[5-9]$)|(^[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]$))
```

- `^`  inicio da lista
- `[5-9]` pega qualquer valor de 5 a 9
- `$` fim da lista
- `|` "ou". Assim permite procurar na proxima regex caso a primeira falhe
- `^[1-9][0-9]` isso pega qualquer valor de 10 a 99 (*)
- `[0-9]$` = opcional ai pega qualquer coisa  de 1 a 9 que seja o ultimo caracter da lista.

(*) - o `?` quer dizer opcional. Quando colocado assim dentro de `^[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]$`  quer dizer que a verficação do meio é opcional, o que permite numeros entre 10 e 99.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. Agradeço pelas explicações.